# How can I get the name of a scriptable object via code

Tags: unity

How can I get the name of a scriptable object, same way I would a game object `gameObject.name`?

I've tried:

```
object.name
scriptableObject.name
ScriptableObject.name
name
this.name

//String GetName()
WorldObjectData obj = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<WorldObjectData>();
SerializedObject serializedObject = new SerializedObject(obj);
return serializedObject.FindProperty("m_name");
```

I can see that ScriptableObject extends Object, which has the .name attribute. But cant access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you started by trying the most obvious thing, `object.name`, the same way you would with a game object?

They both inherit from `UnityEngine.Object` w[hich is where the `.name` field is defined](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-name.html).

Comment: Yes, this does not work, or Im doing it wrong

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Edit your question to show in detail what you're doing, what outcome you expect, and what outcome you're getting instead.

Comment: Okay, Edited, thanks

Comment: I see the issue now I think, Im using a field variable `name`, which hides Object.name

Comment: This is why it's important to show what you've tried *in its full context* in your question. ie. Your first post should have included the whole script that exhibits the problem, so we could see and point out the member shadowing the name field.